# Smoothness of functions and embedded submanifolds

Tags: smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions, submanifold

I am studying differential geometry and in the lecture notes I came across this lemma. For the proof it is said to be a good exercise, but I have my doubts about the prove of my part and no clue how to do the other way around.

Given is an embedded submanifold $M \subset N$ and another manifold $P$.
I want to prove that $f:P \to M$ is smooth iff $f:P\to N$ is smooth.

My attempt:
If $f:P \to M$ smooth then $f:P \to N$ smooth.
Let $\phi$ be a chart of $P$ and $\chi$ a chart of $M$ then we know:
$\chi\circ f\circ\phi^{-1}$ is smooth. Let $i$ be the inclusion map from M to N then:
$\chi \circ (i\circ\ f)\circ \phi^{-1}$ is also smooth.

I don't think this is the right approach any help or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Since $M$ is embedded in $N$, the inclusion map is an embedding and hence it is smooth. So, the composition $i \circ f$ is also a smooth map. For the converse, see that embedded manifolds have subspace topology and hence you can form charts on $M$ by using charts on $N$.

Comment: Do I restrict the charts of N to the open in M induced by that topology?

Comment: Yes, but you have to be careful since the embedded manifold may be with boundary or even corners. You can look at John Lee's book for this.